# PHP JSON Array - how to modify a json code Group by the same value

Tags: php, json

I grouped my table by objects with the same value with php foreach function

```
$data = json_decode($geo, true);
$out = [];
foreach($data as &$element) {
     $out[$element['id']][] = [
        'lng' => $element['lng'],
        'lat' => $element['lat'],
        'time' => $element['time']
    ];
};
$geo = json_encode($out);
```

later I got this result

```
"[{

"1":[{"lng":134.94157,"lat":36.871337,"time":1502159287}],

"2":[{"lng":134.94157,"lat":34.598832,"time":1502211838}],

"3":[{"lng":131.225,"lat":37.101667,"time":1502144333},{"lng":131.24,"lat":37.123333,"time":1502144343}]
}]"
```

now I want my data to be like this

```
[

[{"lng":134.94157,"lat":36.871337,"time":1502159287}],

[{"lng":134.94157,"lat":34.598832,"time":1502211838}],

[{"lng":131.225,"lat":37.101667,"time":1502144333},{"lng":131.24,"lat":37.123333,"time":1502144343}]

]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) your initial JSON data. Then, move to the first index in the decoded data and only pick values of the array's values skipping the keys with the help of [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
<?php

$prev_json = '[{"1":[{"lng":134.94157,"lat":36.871337,"time":1502159287}],"2":[{"lng":134.94157,"lat":34.598832,"time":1502211838}],"3":[{"lng":131.225,"lat":37.101667,"time":1502144333},{"lng":131.24,"lat":37.123333,"time":1502144343}]}]';

$data = json_decode($prev_json,true);

$new_json = json_encode(array_values($data[0]));

echo $new_json;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/bFmYn

**Update:** Looking at your updated code, you could remove the `$element['id']` from `$out[$element['id']]` and make it as `$out[] = [..rest of your code..]` and it should work.

Comment: @Mabdo Glad to help. I have also updated my answer to make it much simpler.